# Getting error Class 'Codeigniter\Model' not found in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, web

I'm facing this error and it`s weird I check everywhere and I think the code is good.
the problem is I want an instance from my model in controller but it gives the error above
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34Tj1.png)
I 'll put the code below.
this is controller

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers\User;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;

use App\Models\UserModel;

class Users extends BaseController{

    public function index(){
        echo view('includes/header');
        echo view('user/index');
        echo view('includes/footer');
    }

    public function login(){

    }
    public function register(){

        $model = new UserModel();

        if($this->request->getPost()){
            return "f";
        }
        
        echo view('includes/header');
        echo view('user/register');
        echo view('includes/footer');
    }

}
```

this is model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Codeigniter\Model;

class UserModel extends Model
{

    protected $table      = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $returnType     = 'array';
    protected $useSoftDeletes = true;

    protected $allowedFields = ['email', 'username', 'password'];

    protected $useTimestamps = true;
    protected $createdField  = 'created_at';
    protected $updatedField  = 'updated_at';
    protected $deletedField  = 'deleted_at';

    protected $validationRules    = [
        'email' => 'required|valid_email',
        'username' => 'required|min_length[2]|max_length[10]',
        'password' => 'required|min_length[8]|max_length[20]'
    ];
    protected $validationMessages = [
        'email' => [
            'required' => 'This field is required',
            'valid_email' => 'email is not valid make sure you wrote it right'
        ],
        'username' => [
            'required' => 'This field is required',
            'min_length' => 'the min username is 2',
            'max_length' => 'the max username is 10'
        ],
        'password' => [
            'required' => 'This field is required',
            'min_length' => 'the min pasword is 8',
            'max_length' => 'the max pasword is 20'
        ]
    ];
    // protected $skipValidation     = false;

}
```

please help I'm stuck in there :(

..............................

Comment: most likely: *Any files and directory names passed into the view() function MUST match the case of the actual directory and file itself or the system will throw errors on case-sensitive platforms. You can read more about it [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/outgoing/views.html).*, same goes for controllers and models

Comment: @VPrezn the error message says that it cannot fine `Codeigniter\Model`, have you tried `CodeIgniter\Model` instead?

Answer (score 2):

the file name you used is:

`use Codeigniter/Model`

replace it with :

`use CodeIgniter/Model`

Comment: since when are we doing forward backslash ('/') when creating a model? see: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html#creating-your-model

Comment: ok my bad but the main error was camel casing you called 'Codeigniter' but on linux serves file naming is sensitive you should replace it with 'CodeIgniter' that's it.